# Jquery para quitar autocompletar de todos los formularios del proyecto

Tags: jquery, autocompletar

Poniendo esta instruccion de jqery en cada pagina me quita el autocompletar los formularios pero solo de esa pagina:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

    $("form").attr('autocomplete', 'off');

</script>
```

El probleama es que recargo las paginas en el proyecto mediante ajax por lo que los formularios creados dinamicamente no se les aplica el autocomplete="off" Habia pensado poner la isntruccion  $("form").on para que los formularios creados dinamicamente añadirles la propiedad autocomplete off. he probado de esta manera y no funciona.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

$(document).on( "ready", function() {
$("form").attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});


</script>
```

¿que solucion podria tener?

Comment: Has probado a añadirla en el onsuccess del ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Para elementos que están al principio de la carga de la pagina esta bien lo que tienes pero para los dinámicos en el ajax te hace falta poner esto.

```
$.ajax({
  /***/
  success: function(){
     $("form").attr('autocomplete', 'off');
  },
})
```

Comment: Ya pero si yo añadiese un formulario dinamicamente mediante .append no me valdria...

Comment: pues alli te toca poner a ti el atributo manualmente si haces el append.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre una solución. con este codigo en la cabecera de la pagina me quita el autocompletar de todos los inputs del proyecto,  esten dentro de un formulario o no, se cree en la parte de cliente o de servidor.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("focus","input",function(event){
    $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off')
  });

});


</script>
```